# loop using JavaScript based in html id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if i have a table with an `infinite` which has an input type checkbox. Each check box is marked with an `id` eg. #det1, #det2 , #det3   how would i write my JS loop to check if that certain checkbox is checked to perform the function on it, without writing out each `id` ,because this `id` is also incremented based on the product uploader so for each product uploaded it will just add 1 to the id,at the end i could sit with allot of id's.

javascript that works adding the id manually:

```
 $('#details1, #details2').on('change', function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(row).show();
    }
    else {
        $(row).hide();
    }
 });
```

So that works but because have so many `id`'s based on my `tr`'s i would just like to do a loop and check if that `id` exist (*it could be id = `#details999`*) and if it does do function `on.change`.

(*for each product ill upload the id adds 1 to it  eg. product1 = `#details1` , product2 = `#details2`, etc...*)

There might be a better way of implementing the idea but as im newbie i am open to any suggestions.

What i tried:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < ?; i++) {
   $('#details'+ i).on('change', function(){
   var row = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(row).show();
    }
    else {
        $(row).hide();
      }
     })
    }
```

i know `?` means nothing but i realized i cant set a limit to that also don't want a infinite loop so i'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a common class to the `select` elements and use that to target them

```
<input type="checkbox" id="details1" class="details-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="details2" class="details-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="details3" class="details-checkbox">
```

and then use

```
$('.details-checkbox').on('change', function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(row).show();
    }
    else {
        $(row).hide();
    }
 });
```

Comment: @Andreas oups :) fixed.

Comment: ended up using this as it feels like the safer option.. thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

I would use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```js
$('table').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e) {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');

  $(row).toggle($(this).prop('checked'));
})
```

```css
tr.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Details 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Details 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Details 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr class="hidden"><td colspan="2">Details 4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be safer to add the `[id^="details"]` to the delegated selector to avoid misfires from other checkboxes.

Comment: That would be a thing to consider (or better use a common class as suggested in your answer). But as this is just meant to provide a possible way and not a 100% bulletproof solution, I will leave this to the TO :)

Comment: well this worked 100% as wanted it to, thanks so much @Andreas for explanation and solution, wil do bit more research on this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input:checkbox[id*=details ]').on('change',function(){
 var row = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
 if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(row).show();
 }
 else {
    $(row).hide();
    }
 });
```